# Repetitive I know: Rock Paper Scissors Code academy. Why does the prompt not show up?

Tags: javascript, prompt

It appears that my prompt below is not showing up. I cannot get this code to work. I am still a beginner coder but I have been coding for about 3 months now.

```
<html>
<title>Random Code</title>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var userChoice = prompt("Choose Rock Paper or Scissor!").toUpperCase();
    //this prompt is not showing up.
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < .34) {
      computerChoice = "ROCK";
    } else if (computerChoice > .33 && computerChoice <= .67) {
      computerChoice = "PAPER";
    } else {
      computerChoice = "SCISSORS";
    }
    document.write("Computer: " + computerChoice);

    var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
      if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return ("The result is a tie!")
      } else if (choice1 === "ROCK" && choice2 === "PAPER") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + computerChoice + ". You lose");
      } else if (choice1 === "ROCK" && choice2 === "SCISSORS") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You win!");
      } else if (choice1 === "PAPER" && choice2 === "ROCK") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
      } else if (choice1 === "PAPER" && choice2 === "SCISSORS") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
      } else if (choice1 === "SCISSORS" && choice2 === "ROCK") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
      } else if (choice1 === "SCISSORS" && choice2 === "PAPER") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + computerChoice + ". You win!");
      } else {
        return ("You entered an invalid input");
      }
    }

    document.write("User choice: " + userChoice);
    document.write("Computer choice: " + computer Choice);
    document.getElementById("rps").innerHTML = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <p id="rps"></p>



</body>

</html>
```

If you have any pointers or suggestions I'd be forever grateful!

Comment: You have a typo on `computer Choice`. Press F12 to open the developer console and see the errors.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Any syntax errors in the code would prevent it from running at all.

Comment: Another pointer. Indentation makes code MUCH easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
document.write("Computer choice: " + computer Choice);
```

should be

```
document.write("Computer choice: " + computerChoice);
```

You should also move the script at the bottom of the page.

```html
<html>
<title>Random Code</title>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>
  <p id="rps"></p>


  <script>
    var userChoice = prompt("Choose Rock Paper or Scissor!").toUpperCase();
     //this prompt is not showing up.
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < .34) {
      computerChoice = "ROCK";
    } else if (computerChoice > .33 && computerChoice <= .67) {
      computerChoice = "PAPER";
    } else {
      computerChoice = "SCISSORS";
    }

    document.write("Computer: " + computerChoice);

    var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
      if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return ("The result is a tie!")
      } else if (choice1 === "ROCK" && choice2 === "PAPER") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + computerChoice + ". You lose");
      } else if (choice1 === "ROCK" && choice2 === "SCISSORS") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You win!");
      } else if (choice1 === "PAPER" && choice2 === "ROCK") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
      } else if (choice1 === "PAPER" && choice2 === "SCISSORS") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
      } else if (choice1 === "SCISSORS" && choice2 === "ROCK") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
      } else if (choice1 === "SCISSORS" && choice2 === "PAPER") {
        return ("The computer chose:" + computerChoice + ". You win!");
      } else {
        return ("You entered an invalid input");
      }
    }

    document.write("User choice: " + userChoice);
    document.write("Computer choice: " + computerChoice);
    document.getElementById("rps").innerHTML = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Aww my answer was first :(

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly but have you checked the box in the prompt that says 'prevent this page from creating additional dialogues'. Try your app in an incognito page.

Comment: No, that's not it. Trying to figure out answer and not that.

Comment: Yep. I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code in jsfiddle and commented everything out but the first, it worked fine. After a little of "fiddling" I found your error. Line 34 had

```
document.write("Computer choice: " + computer Choice);
```

instead of

```
document.write("Computer choice: " + computerChoice);
```

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Choose Rock Paper or Scissor!", "rps").toUpperCase();
//this prompt is not showing up.
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < .34){
computerChoice = "ROCK";
} else if (computerChoice > .33 && computerChoice <= .67){
computerChoice = "PAPER";
}else{
computerChoice = "SCISSORS";
}document.write("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
if (choice1 === choice2){
    return ("The result is a tie!")
}else if (choice1 === "ROCK" && choice2 === "PAPER"){
    return("The computer chose:" + computerChoice + ". You lose");
}else if (choice1 === "ROCK" && choice2 === "SCISSORS"){
    return("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You win!");
}else if (choice1 === "PAPER" && choice2 === "ROCK"){
    return("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
} else if (choice1 === "PAPER" && choice2 === "SCISSORS"){
    return("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
} else if (choice1 === "SCISSORS" && choice2 === "ROCK"){
    return("The computer chose:" + choice2 + ". You lose.");
} else if (choice1 === "SCISSORS" && choice2 === "PAPER"){
    return("The computer chose:" + computerChoice + ". You win!");
} else {
return("You entered an invalid input");
}
}

document.write("User choice: " + userChoice);
document.write("Computer choice: " + computerChoice);
document.getElementById("rps").innerHTML = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

```html
<p id="rps"></p>
```

:)

Comment: Yup this definitely did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: can you mark this as answer? :D